# Pod view controller presenting issue

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, cocoapods

I am trying to present a view controller inside a pod I created,

I have an Example project that uses the Pod (created through "pod lib create"). If I run the following code in my local view controller everything goes well, the viewDidLoad method is called :

```
MySecondViewController *vc = [[MySecondViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:true completion:nil];
```

But I cannot achieve to present a controller thats in my Pod : a black screen is showed and the viewDidLoad method is not called.

From the Example project, I replace the above code with :

```
[ThePodInterface.shared showDashboard: self];
```

The function gets called internally, in the methods body I execute the following code (the same as the local one but for presenting a VC thats inside the pod) :

```
SomeVCInsideThePod *vc = [[SomeVCInsideThePod alloc] init];

[sourceController presentViewController:vc animated:true completion:nil];
```

sourceController is the parameter name.

The presented VC is black, I have no idea why (could it be due to the self pointer being released early ?) and no logs are displayed.

Comment: Why don't you use `[self sourceController ...]`?

Comment: Does your code work without pod? You don't need to load a MySecondViewController linked with a Xib/Storyboard?

Comment: sourceController is a parameter here in the framework here.
@Larme I am trying to push a dummy view controller thats inside a library The final thing I am trying to achieve is to package some Unity 3D generated Xcode project into some framework.
So some user can use the library to makeKeyAndVisible Unity window etc through a framework interface I defined.
To do so, I am at a first glance trying to simply present some custom view controller that is embedded inside the framework, I don't use XIB/storyboard to simplify things I just try to push a VC with some background color.